# How get specific html from a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am fetching html from a website. I want to get specific html from that page not all how to get that? I have tried following;

before appending data to target below

```
container.html(data);
```

I want to do like `data.find('.site-header').html();` and then do `container.html(data);`

How can I achieve that?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7avm/101/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function () {
    var container = $('#target');
    var url = 'http://aamirshahzad.net';

    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?" +
        "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22" + encodeURIComponent(url) +
        "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",

    function (data) {
        if (data.results[0]) {
            var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
            container.html(data);
        } else {
            var errormsg = '<p>Error: could not load the page.</p>';
            container.html(errormsg).focus().effect('highlight', {
                color: '#c00'
            }, 1000);
        }
    });

});


function filterData(data) {
    // filter all the nasties out
    // no body tags
    data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g, '');
    // no linebreaks
    data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g, '');
    // no comments
    data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g, '');
    // no noscript blocks
    data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g, '');
    // no script blocks
    data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g, '');
    // no self closing scripts
    data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/, '');
    // [... add as needed ...]
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You call the `getJSON` function asking for XML (`format=xml`) and get a HTML response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply;

`container.html($(data).find('.site-header'));`

Comment: Yeah Indeed sometime it won't work with no reason :D Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after `container.html(data);`:

```
container.html(container.find(".site-header"));
```

[Here is your updated **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N7avm/106/)